# Accepting a previous offer while negotiation still pending?

Tags: salary, job-offer, united-states, negotiation

I recently received a verbal offer, where the terms were explained and then asked if I found them acceptable. I mentioned that I had other offers coming and that the salary could potentially be improved (I gave a specific number - not saying it was necessary to hit but would be prefered). We ended the call with the understanding that I was very interested in the position regardless of the salary and that they were very excited and impressed with my qualifications.

I've now been waiting two days for an update on negotiations and since the call I've decided that the initially proposed offer is good and I would like to accept it.

Is it OK for me to reach out and just say that I would like to accept the initial offer? Or do I need to wait to hear from them regarding our negotiation?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to wait to see if they're willing to go up on salary?

Comment: I'm getting anxious that they may be reaching out to other candidates or about to rescind the offer. My current work situation is pretty bad so I want to get out ASAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get on the phone to them straight away. You can perhaps be a little bit cagey and ask if there's been any movement on the money first, but don't waste any more time if there hasn't.

A good fallback position on the salary question is to say that you're keen to get started and show them your worth, but would like it to be reviewed once you've been doing the job for a while. You've then got a few months to turn yourself into someone who is very expensive for them to replace.

Comment: Thanks this is basically what I was expecting so I followed your advice. My fears were unfounded and we ended up meeting in the middle!

Answer (score 2):

If things are really that bad at your current job, contact the person who made the offer directly and tell them that you thought about the offer as a whole and that you are happy with it. Do it as soon as possible if you really think the initial offer is about to be rescinded.